# When did "sink" start referring to the tap as well?

Tags: meaning, historical-change

A current TikTok trend involves someone asking another person to "turn off the sink". In a play with the term "turn off", the second person then goes to the sink and says something repellant enough for the sink to stop the faucet's flow.

While some videos refer to the tap or faucet, most refer to the sink, which presumes that *sink* describes the faucet, as well as the drain.

The NOAD somewhat ambiguously agrees:

> a fixed basin with a water supply and a drain

Merriam-Webster allow for a water supply, but distance it from the meaning of sink:

> a stationary basin connected with a drain and usually a water supply for washing and drainage

The Cambridge dictionary eschews the supply altogether:

> a bowl that is attached to the wall in a kitchen or bathroom in which you wash dishes or your hands, etc.

Dictionary.com brings the supply back into the definition, though still in a secondary way:

> a basin or receptacle, as in a kitchen or laundry, usually connected with a water supply and drainage system, for washing dishes, clothing, etc.

In all these definitions, the basin is clearly the important part – a faucet alone does not make a sink – but the definitions differ in whether and how they include a faucet. Is a sink a basin that *includes* a water supply? Is a sink a basin that is *accompanied* by a water supply, which is itself not a part of the sink? Is a water supply relevant at all, as long as there is a basin and a drain for water to sink into?

According to the TikTok trend, many of us understand *sink* to include the faucet. This is certainly my own definition, as an American born in the 1990s. For Americans I've asked over 50, though, the sink definitively does not include the faucet.

Is this a matter of time, or perhaps of region? When and where did sink begin referring to the water supply as well, and how widely used is this meaning today?

Comment: Originally the would-be faucet was a bucket of water hauled in from the pump outside.

Comment: I'm over 50, and I think the sink includes the faucet. But just from the name, I assume that long enough ago, it didn't.

Comment: Without a tap, turning off the sink would have to be a mime play, to humor the person objecting.

Comment: In my (BrE) variety, a sink has a tap, but I would not use the word _sink_ to include the tap, and _turn off the sink_, while understandable, is utterly bizarre. (And I never met the word "faucet" until I started reading American books and comics).

Comment: A sink and basin are the same thing. They both have faucets (AmE) or taps (AmE OR BrE). He installed the sink but didn't have time to install the faucet or tap.

Comment: For me (and I am British) a sink is something into which waste flows, usually to be disposed of or to dissipate naturally. In some sinks the waste can merely accumulate. Any water supply is incidental. This is particularly true of some of the other uses of 'sink'. If sinks always had a water supply then terms likre 'sink estate' and 'heat sink' would not have developed.

Comment: @BoldBen surely it's not always waste in the sink(/basin), but (for example) washing water that will become waste after use then be drained away. Of course the supply is only implied and could equally be a bucket

Comment: Can't 'turn off the sink' be regarded as an abbreviation of 'turn off the tap at the sink'? One may think that it is obvious that would be turned off is a tap, and that the important thing to specify is which tap (the one at the sink, rather than, say, the one at the bathtub). Analysing 'turn off the sink' in that way makes it understandable why people would say it, while holding on to the traditional definition of *sink*, which excludes the tap.

Comment: @ChrisH It's true that the water does not start out as waste in the case of a kitchen or laboratory sink but the intention is that it will become waste once it has been used. This is in contrast to the water which is run from the same tap into a pan, jug or beaker for culinary or scientific purposes. I agree whileheartedly, however, that a sink can exist without a piped water supply, it can even exist without piped drainage if its drain empties into a bucket. I would contend, though, that a basin or bowl used for the same purpose is not a sink as it has no drain.

Comment: @BoldBen that's about right - certainly the one in my campervan that drains into a jerrycan doesn't stop being a sink

Comment: It is _metonymy_ where a tap/faucet is referred to by the name of something closely associated with that thing, a sink. It can be a short form of "kitchen sink faucet, bathroom sink faucet" also; and there is the term _sink spout_ in US English as well. Although, this is just a conjecture. Online language is evolving fast.

Comment: The real problem is with the phrase "turn off" -- turn off is an action that really only makes sense to something that is currently 'on' or is currently 'running'. So, that's why we can say "turn off the TV", for example. Because we say "the TV is on", so it makes sense you can "turn it off." The only way you could sensibly say "turn off the sink" is if you could also say "the sink is on" or "the sink is running" and I've never heard someone say that. Instead, we say that "the water is running" or "the water is on". That's why "turn off the water" makes sense and is often said.

Comment: One instance does not make it a new distinct meaning. A number of instances in the wild should be found of "turn off the sink" or other replacements of 'tap/faucet' with 'sink'.

Comment: With a cursory glance at googling for "turn off the sink", most of the first hits are for things related to the TikTok, including this question here on ELU. But there are some instances of real usage. It sounds a little weird to me but then I suppose the classic metonymy "boil the kettle" is kinda weird if you think about it. But in that phrase 'kettle' still doesn't have a new meaning itself (at least not yet).

Comment: So a case must be made and supported for 'sink' to have the actual additional meaning of 'tap'. Otherwise it's just metonymy.

Comment: So, a quick search revealed that some people do seem to use this (outside of TikTok) in blogs related to saving water, e.g. "Those extra gallons add up, especially if occasionally forget to turn off the sink while you shave". It sounds a little bit weird outside of context, just thinking of the phrase "turn off the sink", but I suppose if I read those blogs in context, it's not too absurd as it sounds in this Question. In any case, though, the TikTok trend appears to just be a trend; it'll be gone and forgotten in a month or so.

Answer (score 1):

I personally have never heard nor said this, though I'm from Australia so maybe it hasn't caught on here yet or we have a preference for tap. When you think about it though, it makes sense I guess. Turn off the sink. Turn off the shower. Turn off the bath. You can be more specific. Turn off the tap, which tap when there are many in a household? If it is obvious though, I would still prefer "the tap"

Answer (score 0):

The following extract from [THE HISTORY OF THE SINK](https://www.kingstonbrass.com/blog/the-history-of-the-sink/) explains the evolution  from the original “basin” to modern times sinks. A hand pump was used  before water taps were supplied.

> ***Originally, a sink was nothing more than a basin.*** In the early 1700s, most homes came with a washstand, which acted as the bathroom sink. A washstand was a simple fixture consisting of a deep bowl and a small table. Often a pitcher was placed next to the deep bowl. In a way, the pitcher acted as a faucet, providing water to the static basin.
>
> ***Next up is the mid-1800s to early 1900s, when they shifted to what some called a dry sink.*** These basins were made of stone, wood, or metal and were set into a cabinet or window sill. In some cases, households even added a backsplash to the dry sink. To fill these basins with water, it was necessary to bring a bucket of water to the sink.
> ***Over time, the hand pump was added to the sink, often only available to the wealthiest of homeowners.***

Comment: This is intersting, but it doesn't answer the question, which is about how the use of the **word** _sink_ has apparently evolved in recent years.

Comment: @ColinFine - I dispute that it _has_ 'evolved' in that way, and around my location,  saying 'turn off the sink' would make people think you were foreign or if not, maybe had had a stroke.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: my experience matches yours, but other comments on this topic suggests that not all English speakers agree with us.

Comment: I've also never heard this new use (I don't do TikTok). I suspect it may be regional or ideosyncratic, but the Internet meme is causing it to spread quickly.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey where I come from (NYC), "turn off the sink" is a perfectly reasonable and understandable thing to say.